# Do I have to override `onEditorAction` or does "action_done" has a default behavior?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText view:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

I want to disable the "`enter`" key when user insert input.

Instead I want the keyboard to have a "done" key that will close the softkeyboard.

does adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` isn't enough?

The "enter" key is still on my Nexus 4 and no `done` key is there.

Do I have to override `onEditorAction` or does "`action_done`" has a default behavior?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Add `android:singleLine="true"` in your `EditText`

Comment: Actually you bring up a good point.  I know several keyboard take multiline to mean "always show a newline key, no matter what else".  That just might work.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard itself decides what to do with the ime options.  Your keyboard may have decided not to display ime option strings.  I don't blame them-  having done it, morphing the enter key like that is a pain in the ass, and as many users complained about it as liked it.  There's no way to force it to, it depends on that particular keyboard having decided to code it in.

Comment: ok so not displaying the "done" string, but why does it still acts like "enter new line" and not close my softkey ?

Comment: They may not have done any kind of dynamic effect on it.  The keyboard has to actively decide to call the action function rather than send a \n keystroke, it isn't android magic translating between the two.  And from my time at Swype, about 50% of users hated it when it did and just wanted it to always be newline.  So whatever keyboard your using may have decided not to do it on purpose.

Comment: Basically anything you tell the keyboard is a request.  It may or may not honor it.  Hooray when it does, but don't expect it to.

Comment: ANd check out Hariharan's answer-  he may be right on about the keyboard deciding to always show an enter key because you set it to be multiline.